# Python list Index Out of range while Converting Tuple to List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

As studying Python I got stuck in a Problem where GeeksforGeeks is telling us that To convert a tuple to List we can use this process `variable_name = list(tuple_variable_name)` but implementing this process to my sample code doesn't work **BTW I am getting the input using sys.stdin.read()**

Here is my code which I am trying to run in my Pycharm

```
import sys,ast
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

def my_sort(a1):
    a = list(a1)
    for i in a:
        if (a[i]%5) < (a[i+1]% 5):
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = temp
    print(a)

my_sort(input_list)
```

Can anyone help me in clearing out my doubts or Understanding These Concepts

Comment: `for` loops don’t produce indexes in python, they give you the elements of the list. Try printing `i `.

Comment: `for i in a:` `i` here is not indexes, so `a[i]` is definitely not what you are expecting it to be.

Comment: My Objective was to sort the elements according to the remainder when divided by 5    Can anyone help me in making my code produce the output like this

Comment: Do you need to do this manually? Python’s `sort` function can work for this in one line of code.

Comment: yea Python     `sorted` function is doing its work correctly when i tested it as a hunt but i want the entered input to be sorted as     **Sorted according to the remainder when divided the inputs with 5**

Comment: I understand that @AlexMercer, still: `sorted(input_list, key=lambda n: n % 5)`

Comment: Thanks Mark This worked but it only checks for two numbers not the whole list

Comment: The above will sort the entire list by modulus 5 of each item — it will compare every item. Because your question is based on user input, it's not 100% clear what you are trying to do (we don't know what you're inputing, what `input_list` is). It would be helpful if you gave us the actual input to your function and the expected output.

Comment: So finally I got my answer as i was expecting as @mark asked the input and output this question was given by my friend so here the input should look like     `1,9,35,12,13,21,10` and the output should look like     `[35, 10, 1, 21, 12, 13, 9]` which i got after implementing @mark's algorithm

Comment: so can i answer my own Question as i assume that my reputation will be decreased as already it is not far away from     **ZERO** Can I?

Comment: Can you edit to your post to clarify things as you have done here in the comments? As @MarkMeyer mentioned, we can't do much without seeing the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be worth posting a simple, complete example, since the discussion in the comments lead to a bunch of new information which isn't obvious in the post.

```py
#str_in = input('Enter the numbers to sort: ')
str_in = '1,9,35,12,13,21,10'

nums = [int(elem) for elem in str_in.split(',')]

sorted_nums = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x % 5)

print(sorted_nums)
```

Output:

```py
[35, 10, 1, 21, 12, 13, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `for i in a` to `for i in range(len(a))`:

```
import sys,ast
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

def my_sort(a1):
    a = list(a1)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (a[i]%5) < (a[i+1]% 5):
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = temp
    print(a)

my_sort(input_list)
```

`for i in a` loops over each element in `a` while `for i in range(len(a))` loops over each index.

Comment: Output Remains the same        `list index out of scope`

Comment: Oh, on the last iteration of the loop, indexing `a[i+1]` goes out of scope. What happens if you try `range(len(a)) - 1`?

Comment: `range(len(a))-1` worked but only for the middle elements the end elements were juggled from here to there